# using # tag to navigate using backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, href, router, hashtag

I am using backbone.js routers to do navigation in my single page app.

Code excerpts to explain my problem :

```
routes: {
    'action/:id' : performAction
}
```

In order to access this I have my anchor element , with href="#action/121"

My host url is http://mypage.com/test.html.

Problem is , when I click on this anchor tag my url changes to

http://mypage.com/action/121

And the router code is also not reached , Do not know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Wouldn't happen to have set the `pushState` flag to true?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are activating history push, be sure to disable it running this(instead of what you have):

Backbone.history.start({pushState: false});